# How can I get the launcher to recognize another icon of an application already on the launcher?

Tags: launcher, chromium

How do I add another icon in the Launcher for an application that is already present. A second Chromium icon specifically, and then name them differently?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the file `~/.local/share/applications/chromium Web Browser.desktop` to something like chromium-2.desktop, then add a unique StartupWMClass:

```
StartupWMClass=youruniquename
```

This should allow Unity to think the icon is a different application.